# Use an instance of the standard class vector to implement the queue. How does this implementation compare with array based approach?

Tags: java, for-loop, syntax-error

Here is my code. I have a weird error that I cant figure out. Any and every help would be greatly appreciated. I am a beginner at this level.

```
public interface QueueInterface<T>
{
  public void enqueue(T newEntry);

  public T dequeue();

  public T getFront();

  public boolean isEmpty();

  public void clear();
```

Now I am putting the code for Vector Class which is implemented by the above code. I need help on this part. I think there is an error in the for loop but I am not sure.

```
    import java.util.Vector;
public class VectorQueue implements QueueInterface
{
  private Vector queue;
  private int frontIndex;
  private int backIndex;

  private boolean initialized=false;
  private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY= 50;
  private static final int MAX_CAPACITY= 1000;

  public VectorQueue()
  {
    queue=new Vector<>();
    frontIndex=backIndex=0;

  }
  public void enqueue(T newEntry)
  {
    backIndex++;
    queue.add(backIndex, newEntry);

    if(frontIndex==0)
      frontIndex++;
  }
    public T dequeue()
  {
    if(frontIndex!=0)
    {
      T rEntry=queue.elementAt(frontIndex);
      for (int i =frontIndex;i++)
             queue.add(frontIndex, queue.elementAt(frontIndex+1));
           queue.remove(backIndex);
           backIndex--;
           if(backIndex==0)
             frontIndex=0;
           return rEntry;
    }
    return null;
    }
    public T getFront()
    {
      if(frontIndex!=0)
        return queue.elementAt(frontIndex);
      return null;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
      if(backIndex==0)
        return true;
      return false;
    }
    public void clear()
    {
      int index=backIndex;
      for(int i=frontIndex;i<=backIndex;i++)
        queue.removeElementAt(index--);
      frontIndex=backIndex=0;
    }
  }
```

Comment: **I think there is an error in the for loop**, actually errors are not in for-loops, but errors are in the numerous ways people write for loops

Comment: Why are you manually handling the indices? If it's for homework or you are working on actually implementing a data structure for some reason it'd make more sense to use an array or custom linked list implementation as the backing store rather than using a built in data structure that handles the indices and element shifting and ignoring that behavior.

Comment: It is for my homework. Just got stuck at this point and need a little bit of guidance to move forward. Just tried changing few things but still getting some error. It is saying in java error. Symbol T cannot find symbol